# Show that the volume of $n$ dimensional ball of radius $r$ is $r^nv_n$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, measure-theory

Show that the volume of $n$ dimensional ball of radius $r$ is $r^nv_n$ where $v_n$ is the volume of the $n-$dimensional unit ball. Use Cavalieri principle and induction. My problem is implementing the Cavalieri theorem at the induction step. Suppose the volume of a radius $r$ ball is $r^nv_n$. I don't know how to choose the set which is a product of intervals, because I don't know how to choose the function with which I can compute the volume. While it seems intuitive in 2nd and 3rd dimension, I have no clue when it comes to $n$-th dimension. I could use your help. I would like to stress how important it is that I see how Cavalieri principle is used.

Answer (score 1):

Much better to note that the map $\mathbb R^n\ni x\mapsto rx$ has Jacobian $r^n$ (this map takes the unit ball to the ball of radius $r$).

Answer (score 1):

Let $r>0$, the volume of the $n$-sphere of radius $r$ is:
$$\idotsint_{x_1^2 + \dots+x_n^2 < r^2} dx_1\dots dx_n  $$
By using a change of variables: $ry_i = x_i$, the above integral becomes:
$$\idotsint_{(ry_1)^2 + \dots+(ry_n)^2 < r^2} dry_1\dots dry_n = r^n \idotsint_{y_1^2 + \dots+y_n^2 < 1} dy_1\dots dy_n = r^n v_n $$

Answer (score 1):

It is well known  from the measure theory, that  if  $\Psi  : R^n  \to R^n$  is a one-to-one linear mapping, then  for every Lebesgue measurable
set   $ A \subset  R^n$ the equality

$$\lambda_n(\Psi(A))=|J_{\Psi}|    \lambda_n(A) ~~~~~~~~~~~~  (1)$$
 holds true, where $ |J_{\Psi}|$ denotes    Jacobian  of the transformation  $\Psi$.

In your case
$$\Psi(x_1, \cdots, x_n)= (\rho \times x_1, \cdots, \rho \times  x_n)$$  which implies that $ |J_{\Psi}|=\rho^n$.

Let  $B_n(0,r)$  denotes  $n$ -dimensional ball of radius $r$. It is obvious
that $B_n(0,r)=\Psi(B_n(0,1))$.

Then following (1) we get

$$\lambda_n(B_n(0,r) )= \lambda_n(\Psi(B_n(0,1))=|J_{\Psi}|    \lambda_n(B_n(0,1))= \rho^n \times  \lambda_n(B_n(0,1))= \rho^n \times  v_n$$